# matplotlib: no module named compat

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, matplotlib

I have installed python-2.7.5-5ubuntu3 and matplotlib-1.3.1-1ubuntu5 from the ubuntu 14.04 repository via apt-get. Trying to import the library in python 2.7 raises the following import error:

```
 harold@ubuntu:~$ python
 Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
 [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import matplotlib
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
     from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
 ImportError: No module named compat
 >>>
```

I checked the directory /usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib and, indeed, cannot find any package called compat.

Any idea what is broken on my system?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like you are using the wrong version of matplotlib, try http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/index.html

Comment: There should be a folder called compat

Comment: unfortunately, this folder was not there. I now deleted the ubuntu package and installed matplotlib via pip, which works out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

I have found same problem on Ubuntu 16 & 14.
Possible source of the problem is damaged instance of matplotlib. Damaged instance overlaps working instance of matplotlib.
Please try to remove broken instance of matplotlib to solve the issue.
Firstly I have looked matplotlib instances:

```
find / |grep matplotlib | grep __init__\.py$ |more
```

Secondly I have deleted this folder:

```
find /usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib -delete
```